# how to design hidden field in android and it will appear when we click it

Tags: android-emulator

i am try use hidden field like Div tags in android for hiding some field and when we will click that button the related fields will appear.

Answer (score 0):

try setting visibility to GONE this will remove the display. You can then set it to visibile. This will remove the view completely but everything else will still line up properly. If you want to just make it invisible there is an invisible setting too.